# How to load specific set css commands only at the first browsing of the web site?

Tags: html, css

I want to load specific set css commands only at the first loading of the web site.I do not want those sets to load during the navigation after loading. For an instance, consider I want to apply that behaviour to these specific set css codes.

```
div.navbar.navbar-inverse
    {
      -webkit-animation: fadeInDownx 900ms linear ;
      animation: fadeInDownx 900ms linear;
    }
    a#brand
    {
       -webkit-animation: appear 1500ms linear ;
       animation: appear 1500ms linear;
    }
```

I want to know how to do that.

Comment: Please provided a little more context on what you're trying to achieve and how your site works. Are you looking to delay animation?

Comment: I'd recommend using javascript's onLoad() function

Comment: You may need to use a combination of session variables between the client and server (dependent on your server-side software stack) and either Javascript or server-side code to modify the CSS or the page style directly. Raw HTML and CSS know nothing about the user's session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put simple javascript like this in your `<head>` section and trigger it on body load event:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function checkIfVisited () {
            if (!window.localStorage.visitedPreviously) {
                document.body.className += ' first-visit';
            }
            window.localStorage.visitedPreviously = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkIfVisited()">
   …
```

It will set the `visitedPreviously` variable and save it in localStorage (which means it will be preserved forever or until your script/user specifically removes it). Before that though the script checks if this variable exists.

- If it does, it means the script (i.e. page) has been loaded before.
- If it doesn't, it will add a class `"first-visit"` to the `<body>` element

And then in your css take this class into account in your selectors:

```
.first-visit .navbar.navbar-inverse
{
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDownx 900ms linear ;
  animation: fadeInDownx 900ms linear;
}
.first-visit #brand
{
   -webkit-animation: appear 1500ms linear ;
   animation: appear 1500ms linear;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/nutece/edit?html,css

Comment: This is not working. Anyway I am doing this on Asp.nemt mvc5 project. Do you have any idea how to alter this code that suits this kind of environment.

Comment: @WarunaKarunathialaka sorry, I had an error there (the script can be triggered only when `body` actually already exists. I also provided a link to working demo.